# Python: open multiple txt file in a directory

Tags: python

Hi i was going to open multiple txt files in a directory.

But i get error message of

> File "testTopic.py", line 9, in <module>
>           with open(path +i, 'r') as f:
>       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
> 'C:\Users\Documents\FP\TM\Export28011986676_10155756928931677.txt'

I did import os, and i trying to open files that ends with  '.txt'
where by my files all are 122343.txt, 344545.txt, 565464353.txt and carry on.

Comment: The code you posted does not contain the line the error message is pointing to. The code you posted has entirely different problems.

Comment: FIX the indentations first.

Comment: @user2357112 i have update my post, with a new error message

Comment: @UbdusSamad i have fixed the indentations already

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a separator between the path and the file name:

```
path = "C:\Users\Documents\FP\TM\Export\\"
```

(Mind the slash at the end of the path.)

Comment: i tried , but it still cant.   File "testTopic.py", line 5
    path = "C:\Users\Documents\FP\TM\Export\"
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: My bad, I forgot to escape the slash.

Answer (score 0):

or:

you can useing os.path.join

```
import os
os.path.join(path,i)
```